# Installing pivpn on RaspberryPi b3

Tags: jessie-lite

I'm desperately trying to install pivpn with this command:

```
curl -l http://install.pivpn.io | bash
```

but i'm still getting this error message;

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   178  100   178    0     0    573      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--   574
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
curl: (77) error setting certificate verify locations:
  CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
```

However the directories does exits

I'm not a wizard with programming. Can anyone help me?

Comment: At a glance this is a `curl` error and I don't think anything to do with pivpn.  Are you really using `http://` there and not `https://` (with an **s**)?  If that is not just a typo in the question, try.  Otherwise, edit in the output of `stat /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt`.

Answer (score 3):

> `curl -l http://install.pivpn.io | bash`

Are you sure that is the command you used? It does not make sense since it gives 301 error (permanently moved). Using `-L` instead of `-l` works for me. It redirects to the new location: `https://install.pivpn.io`.
This is the location that's giving you problems, because it uses https://.

If I check the pivpn website and github repo I see the install command is indeed

```
curl -L https://install.pivpn.io | bash
```

The error 77 you get could indicate that package ca-certificates is not installed. Try

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ca-certificates
```

before running the pivpn install again.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for your comment install CA-Certificates was the solution after that install the rivpn script worked

Comment: Looks like a good answer, but guess the OP bailed on you before he learned what "upvoting" is all about? OP last seen here over a year ago, but +1 from me :)

Comment: @Huib Please make an answer to your solution and accept it after two days. Only accepting an answer with a click on the tick on its left side will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.